# How to perform code coverage of node js application?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

Do we have a code coverage tool that detects how much code is covered. I don't want to have any testing framework here. Just the way users use it, it should be able to give real time code coverage details. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes – just run your application under a suitable coverage runner such as [`nyc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc):

E.g. if you'd start your app with `npm start`, have `nyc` installed and run with

```
nyc --reporter=lcov npm start
```

Of course you'll need to run for a while (so your users get to cover your app), and then capture the LCOV/HTML report generated.